# Java Swing component initialisation

Tags: java, swing

Is it a good practice to put the initialisation code of a component in a method if it is more than just setting its colour, size and text?

```
// frame initialisation
public void init()
{
    .....

    sectors = new JSlider(10,50,12);
    initSlider();

    .....
}

public void initSlider()
{
    sectors.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    sectors.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    sectors.setSnapToTicks(true);
    sectors.setPaintLabels(true);
    sectors.setPaintTicks(true);
}
```

Comment: i personally prefer organising data into different methods. Others may disagree.

Comment: What it does in and of itself seems fine, but because you can call it multiple times, a better name for it might be `resetSlider()` or something along those lines.

Comment: It’s fine to put such things in separate methods, but those methods should almost always be `private` methods.  Initializing the components is the responsibility of that class and that class alone.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, I'd agree that it does clean up the code, but the method should probably be, at the very least, `protected`.  Another approach might be to have a self contained inner class which extends from `JSlider` and provides the initial configuration itself, at least you won't accidently create a new instance of the slider or call the initialisation chain out of sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no harm in doing this, however, I would recommend you to move the initialisation into its own separate class to have a clean separation of concern.

```
class MySlider extends JSlider{
    public MySlider(){
       super();
       //init statements here
    }
}
```

Then in your frame/main class

```
public void init()
{
    .....
    sectors = new MySlider(10,50,12);
    .....
}
```

Comment: Actually, I just made up this scenario to shorten up the example. In reality,this init method is of a JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be better and it would also make it easier to manage and read the code. This is what i think but at the end of the day it is up to the style of the programmer.